# Is there a simple way to transform my y-axis into log scale ? (Matplotlib, Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my issue. I've got a very simple dataframe (called "stockclose"). Here is the simple code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
stockclose.plot()
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpSjg.png)

The problem is that we barely see the stocks value variations when around 0-10. Therefore, I'd like to set a logarithmic scale on the y-axis, but I didn't find a simple way to do it.

In other words, instead of having 0, 200, 400, etc... I'd like to have something like 0, 10, 10, 100, etc...

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mlm5.png)

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `stockclose.plot(logy=True)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use numpy to apply a logarithm to the y axis. Something like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
y=np.log10(x)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show(0)
```